# How to change/add content inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, ads

I am trying to figure out how to add some text or even adsense to what I believe is .js

Its a working lightbox with a description caption at the bottom, and that caption is what I wish to change.

The code here:

```
  captionOn = function () {
      var description = $CurrEl.attr('title');
      console.log( description );
      if (description != undefined && description.length > 0) {
          $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description 
            + '</div>').appendTo('body');
      }
  },
  captionOff = function () {
      $('#imagelightbox-caption').remove();
  },
```

I have figured out that what I need to change is somewhere around + description +, I have tried to change the word description with plain text, with and without the two + symbols, but that breaks the lightbox. 
That means + description + is needed for lightbox to work, so I tried to use this instead:

```
+ "<div class="align_left">" + description + "</div>" 
+ "<div class="align_right">" + Adsense_code + "</div>" +
```

But that doesn't work, either with or without the + symbols.

So as for now I'm all out of ideas and in search. Keeping the description could be a good thing for image-info for the viewers, but how do I then add text or code next to the description?

Comment: I doubt `description` is required. Chances are your syntax was off. Show us what you initially tried.

Comment: Don't do html+text additions like `$('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>')`, you will easily corrupt your HTML with that. It's more safe to say `$('<div>').attr('id', 'imagelightbox-caption').text(description)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the plain text in quotes in order for it to work. Description is a variable.

```
$('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + "Here is my desired text." + '</div>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following line:

```
$('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
```

Is in fact where the content you want to change is being added. All you need to do is alter "description".

**FYI:**

"description" is a javaScript variable, which can be thought of as something with a name (in this case "description") that stores information, in this case that information is presumably the text you're looking to change.

**Solution:**

Description is being set at the following line.

```
var description = $CurrEl.attr('title');
```

So you can change it to what ever text you like by deleting that line and replacing it with the following.

```
var description = "My fancy new description";
```

Don't forget the quotes and the semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

For the changing the description approach - Since the description comes from the title attribute of the image, if you have access to the HTML output, just change the title attribute on the image.